# GDB/MI redirect stdin and stdout to files

Tags: python, c, linux, gdb

I am using GDB Machine interface to debug binary file which read from stdin and write to sdtout. I would like redirect both stdin and stdout to files. With plain GDB i can use run command like this:

```
run < input.txt > output.txt
```

Is there any way to maybe use GDB/MI command -exec-run similarly to this?

Here is similar question [GDB/MI detecting target waiting for input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610655/gdb-mi-detecting-target-waiting-for-input) but it seems so complex compared to plain gdb solution.

I also have not found anything in docs:
ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_22.html#SEC216

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Its is possible to use MI GDB commands together with GDB commands. So if i need to forward stdin and stdout to file i can do it like this:

1. `-file-exec-and-symbols <filename>` //readfile to debug
2. `-break-insert main` //set breakpoint at main function (or anywhere esle)
3. `run < input.txt > output.txt` //forward stdin and stdout to files
4. `-exec-run`  //start debugging

After this you can run commands like step or -exec-step or anything else like you normally do.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the mi command [-inferior-tty-set](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI-Miscellaneous-Commands.html#index-g_t_002dinferior_002dtty_002dset-2962)
along with the mkfifo utility.